# Method "tableView:didSelectedRowAtIndexPath" in a UITableView embedded into a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've a `UITableView` embedded into a `UIViewController`, I've followed all the steps needed to display a list into the table view and this is working

I've a problem with the following method, it looks like it is invoked but it return `null` instead of the item of the list

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
}
```

thank you to everyone for its thoughts

Alessandro

Comment: Then taking your debugging down a level, e.g. what is the `indexPath.row`? is `self.list` not `nil`? if it's a `NSArray`, how many items does it have in it? have you confirmed this method is actually getting called? etc. Clearly not enough for us to diagnose what's going on, but also clearly some additional diagnostics you have to do. But there's nothing obviously wrong with this method. By the way if this method is not getting called, did you set the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties to point to this view controller?

Comment: Which type is the self.list? Your tableview style is plain or grouped?

Comment: Totally agree with @Rob. Thats the best way to find the issue. Try those steps and let us know what comes up.

Comment: just to make things clear - the `NSLog` prints out `(null)`?

Comment: @konrad, yes the NSLog it prints out (null)

Comment: Make sure list is properly initialized and filled before.

Answer (score 0):

Here below the code, the list is correctly displayed so the outlet and protocol method are set up (delegate, datasource).

The method tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: it prints out (null) instead of the right element in the list

```
//
//  MainViewController.m
//  ProvaTable
//
//  Created by Alessandro on 12/6/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Alessandro. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSArray *listOfObjects;

@end

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
@synthesize listOfObjects = _listOfObjects;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.listOfObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Object 1",@"Object 2", nil];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.listOfObjects count];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell Item";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    }
    // Set up the cell...
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.listOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.listOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
}
```

@end

Comment: actually, it is possible that the list is displayed without the delegate correctly set, so you should make sure that implement `UITableViewDelegate` and set the table's delegate.